# Mysql query contains

Tags: mysql, sql

Table

```
id  name(varhcar)
2   15
3   15,23
4   1315,424
5   1512,2323
6   23,15,345
7   253,234,15
```

I need to find out those values which contains 15 which mean i need 2,3,6,7 not 4,5.
Above is sample data, in real time it can be any number.
Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Use the `FIND_IN_SET()` function, it's in the MySQL documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your database is small, consider using `find_in_set` function:

```
select * from your_table 
where find_in_set('15',name);
```

Consider change the model to master-detail table to increase the speed if you have a big table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of relational model you could adopt to make this an easy problem to solve:

```
TABLE: records

id
2
3
4
5
6
7

TABLE: values

record_id  value
2          15
3          15
3          23
4          1315
4          424
5          1512
5          2323
6          23
6          15
6          345
7          253
7          234
7          15
```

Then you can query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM records
INNER JOIN values ON records.id = values.record_id AND values.value = 15
```

This is the only way you can take good advantage of MySQL's query optimizer.

Not that it's impossible to do what you're trying to do, but it kind of misses the point.

If you're already storing data in this format, you should write a one-time migration to transfer it to this "normalized" format in the programming language of your choice, using something like Java's `split` or PHP's `explode`.